# Paginating nested objects in django restframework

Tags: django

PS : Django 2.0.4 and django-restframework 3.7.7

I am having a Place model to store the details of a place and there is one more model PlacePhoto to store the photos of that place

Place model is something like this:

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=1024, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

and PlacePhoto model is something like this:

```
class PlacePhoto(models.Model):
    place = models.ForeignKey(Place, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                              related_name='photos')
    image = models.ImageField()
```

My Place serializer is something like this:

```
class PlaceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    photos = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Place
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'photos', )

    def get_photos(self, obj):
        photos = obj.photos.all()
        request = self.context.get('request')
        serializer = PlacePhotoSerializer(photos, many=True, context={'request': request})
        paginator = RelationPaginator()
        paginated_data = paginator.paginate_queryset(serializer.data, request)
        return paginator.get_paginated_response(paginated_data)



class RelationPaginator(pagination.PageNumberPagination):
    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return {
            'next': self.get_next_link(),
            'previous': self.get_previous_link(),
            'count': self.page.paginator.count,
            'results': data
        }



class PlacePhotoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = PlacePhoto
        fields = ('image', )
```

I am trying to paginate the photos of a place but unfortunately I am not successful in that.
The request object being passed to paginator is same as that of place api so the photos absolute_uri is same as that of place api.

```
{  
   "count":6,
   "next":"http://localhost:8000/api/v1/places/?page=2",
   "previous":null,
   "results":[  
      {  
         "id":1832,
         "name":"The National",
         "locality":"New York",
         "location":{  
            "latitude":-73.97212481,
            "longitude":40.756645889989
         },
         "visited_count":0,
         "interested_count":0,
         "photos":{  
            "next":"http://localhost:8000/api/v1/places/?page=2",
            "previous":null,
            "count":10,
            "results":[  
               {  
                  "image":"https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/media.testpress.in/buena-dev/places/The%20National/images/cf80a3136a614dd889fc5920829ef289"
               }
            ]
         },
         "price_level":2,
         "types":[  
            "bar",
            "restaurant",
            "food",
            "point_of_interest",
            "establishment"
         ],
         "distance":null
      }
   ]
}
```

Can anyone please guide me how I can paginate the nested data.

Comment: Hi Umair - have you added `REST_FRAMEWORK = { 'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.CursorPagination', 'PAGE_SIZE': 100 }` to your `settings.py` file?

Comment: For anyone struck at this same thing, (sadly) I have put hacky solution for this by overwriting raquest.path with my related model api path and then passing it to serializer and again reverting the same.

Comment: @MichealJRoberts I am using `PageNumberPagination`, make any difference in related object paginated response links ?

Comment: Hmmmm, I don't think so. Try my method below and let me know how you get on...

Answer (score 2):

Try my above comment suggestion, if not, perhaps you need something like this:

```
class RelationPaginator(pagination.PageNumberPagination):
    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response({
            'links': {
                'next': self.get_next_link(),
                'previous': self.get_previous_link()
             }
            'count': self.page.paginator.count,
            'results': data
        })
```

You don't need to set your default to this in `settings.py` provided you use it in `views.py` where necessary:

```
class SomeView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = PlacePhoto.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PlacePhotoSerializer
    pagination_class = RelationPagination
```

***N.B. Disclaimer***: This is a best guess from your custome pagination `RelationPaginator` class, if this doesn't work would likely need your whole code bed to understand why your pagination isn't working...

Answer (score 2):

I think you should override `get_next_link` and `get_previous_link` instead of  `get_paginated_response` in your paginator:

```
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse

from rest_framework.utils.urls import replace_query_param, remove_query_param


class RelationPaginator(pagination.PageNumberPagination):

    def get_next_link(self):
        if not self.page.has_next():
            return None
        url = reverse('your_url_name', request=self.request) ## just pass the url name of the main endpoint that handles the photos list
        page_number = self.page.next_page_number()
        return replace_query_param(url, self.page_query_param, page_number)

    def get_previous_link(self):
        if not self.page.has_previous():
            return None
        url = reverse('your_url_name', request=self.request)  ## just pass the url name of the main endpoint that handles the photos list
        page_number = self.page.previous_page_number()
        if page_number == 1:
            return remove_query_param(url, self.page_query_param)
        return replace_query_param(url, self.page_query_param, page_number)
```

references:

1- [reverse](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/reverse/)